# Converting a pdf stored with multer to text

Tags: express, pdf, multer, pdftotext

I have an express backend that receives a pdf from an angular front end.  I'm trying to store it in disk storage with multer and then use pdf-to-text to convert it to text.

heres the relevant code:

```
const multer = require('multer');
pdfUtil = require('pdf-to-text');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, '_backend/pdfs');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname
    cb(null, name );
  }
});

app.post('/api/pdf', multer({ storage: storage }).single('pdf'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    pdfUrl = __dirname + '/pdfs/' + req.file.originalname;
    pdfUtil.pdfToText(pdfUrl, (data) => {
      console.log(data); //print all text
    });
  });
```

When I run the code in the endpoint as a stand alone node.js module the entire text of the pdf gets printed in the terminal but in the endpoint it gets printed as null.  I've checked and the path to the pdf is correct.  The pdf also get successfully stored in the folder I specified.  I assume it has something to do with the pdf not being fully stored when the pdfToText function is called but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using **pdf-to-text** but you are only printing the output in to the console.

when you run this:

```
    pdfUtil.pdfToText(pdfUrl, (data) => { console.log(data);})
```

You are saying: "Hey NodeJS, please read this url and output all the data object to the console".

In order to save the info into a .txt file you have to use the native File System module of NodeJS.

Try something like this example inside the controller of your API:

```
var pdfUtil = require('pdf-to-text');
var pdf_path = "Your_pdf.pdf";

var option = {from: 0, to: 10};

pdfUtil.pdfToText(pdf_path, option, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw(err);
  fs.writeFile("txtFromPdf.txt", data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

This way you are reading and writing the first 10 pages of your pdf and outputing them into a TXT file called "txtFromPdf.txt", with a non-blocking piece of code.

Be aware that this module will output all the pdf with it's indentations into a "txt" that maybe could be hard to read.

If you are intrested in know more about "fs.writeFile()", you can go to https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback to learn more about it.

Comment: Just to clarify, the final goal wasn't actually to just print it to the console.  That was just a test.  I'm eventually going use rabbitmq to pass it to a python script that uses nltk to analyze it.  Is it not feasible to pass the entire text of the pdf as a string this way?

Comment: Try to use my function in your API. It writes all the pdf as a string in a .txt file

Comment: Alright, I got it to work, thanks.  Out of curiosity, do you know why printing the text to the console wasn't working?

Comment: Because doing a simple console.log () is just that, like sending to stout. You also can store it in something like a global variable, but depending in the size of your pdf it could take a lot of memory.